# Geb: setting the reports dir at runtime

Tags: groovy, geb

I'm writing a little test framework for a site using Geb. As part of my reporting functionality, I'd like to be able to specify at runtime where the *reportsDir* lives. I'm no developer so please excuse any omissions in this question.

Everything I've read so far suggests that this can only be set via the project's configuration or the build adaptor. However, Geb's Configuration class has a [setReportsDir](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.2/api/geb/Configuration.html#setReportsDir%28java.io.File%29) method which I can access from my browser object:

```
def currentConfig = pageBrowser.getConfig()

def reportLocation = "target/runtime_reports_dir"
def reportFile = new File(reportLocation)
reportFile.mkdirs()

File newTarget = new File(reportLocation)
currentConfig.setReportsDir(newTarget)
```

Unfortunately, although this appears to change the *reportsDir* in the browser's config object, the actual output still appears in the directory defined by my configuration.

Is this possible? Could I override the *setupReporting* method in *GebReportingTest* instead (I've not found anything suggesting how this might be done either)?

--- Edit 1 ---

I've tried

```
class MyTest extends GebReportingTest {

    def pageBrowser

    def setup() {
        this.pageBrowser = new Browser()
        this.pageBrowser.config.reportsDir = new File( 'target/runtime_reports_dir' )
    }

    @Test
    void runTestSet() {

        setup()
        this.pageBrowser....
    }
}
```

after Tim's comments but I've had no joy so far. After invoking the setup() method, the pageBrowser's config object returns the reportsDir I've defined in code. However, all instances of the 'report' command store screenshots etc in the directory defined in GebConfig.groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geb will look for GebConfig.groovy in the root of the classpath

You can set reportsDir in there

See:  http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.6.2/configuration.html#reports_dir

#### Edit:

Have you tried:

```
class MyTest extends GebReportingTest {
  void setUp() {
    browser.config.reportsDir = new File( 'target/runtime_reports_dir' )
  }

  @Test
  void runTestSet() {
    // Do testing
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have the reportsDir specified in GebConfig.groovy, as the tests won't run otherwise. My problem is that I would like to be able to override that setting at any point and don't know how to, or even if it's possible.

Comment: have you tried `browser.config.reportsDir = new File( 'target/runtime_reports_dir' )` in the [setup section of each test](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.2/configuration.html#runtime_overrides)?

Comment: I _think_ this is what you were suggesting:   `@RunWith(JUnit4)
class MyTest extends GebReportingTest {

    def pageBrowser

    def setup() {
        this.pageBrowser = new Browser()
        this.pageBrowser.config.reportsDir = new File( 'target/runtime_reports_dir' )
    }

    @Test
    void runTestSet() {

        setup()
        this.pageBrowser....
    }
}`  but unfortunately this didn't work. I tried a couple of variants on setReportsDir as well.

Comment: I've popped my latest attempt in the question body to make it clearer.

Comment: @JamesBartlett Added another thing that I think should work... fingers crossed

Comment: Good news first - that works via browser.drive {}. However, just to be difficult I'm not using that construct (hence instantiating a new Browser object in my example). I'm hazy on why I decided to do it that way to be honest (there were reasons at the time I'm sure) so I may have to play. I don't suppose you know how to do the same with an instantiated Browser object, rather than _browser_?

Comment: @JamesBartlett No idea I'm afraid :-( Does the source for [GebReportingTest](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-junit4/src/main/groovy/geb/junit4/GebReportingTest.groovy) and [GebTest](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-junit4/src/main/groovy/geb/junit4/GebTest.groovy) help any? Hopefully someone else will come along with experience of how to do things this way? In your code above, the `def setup()` should be `void setUp()` btw (if that helps)

Comment: I've done some more noodling and although it's puzzling why I can't change this property on a new Browser instance, Tim's answer does solve the problem for me via another route.

Comment: In my version I needed to have the setup method name  all lower case. ie `setup()` and not `setUp()`. I didn't edit the answer in case the camel case works for some versions and not others.